# Converting file to 2d array in bash

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I am working on a project where I saved some data to a file (data.txt).

```
10010101010;99;18767654536;252525
89878337326;44;18764329087;242424
```

The next step now is to read that data in to a 2D array where row[0] is the first row and row[1] is the second row. I am trying to achieve that goal. Additionally I would love to be able to access the individual elements for each row also

I currently have this code but it only prints the first row and i cant access the elements

```
read -a rows < data.txt                                          
for row in "${rows[@]}";do                                                      
  row_array=(${row})                                                            
  first=${row_array[0]} 
  sec=${row_array[1]}                                                        
  echo ${first}
  echo ${sec}                                                                 
done
```

Comment: Bash doesn't have 2D arrays. [What are you trying to do with the data?](http://xyproblem.info/) There's probably a way to do it without reading all the data into an in-memory array. Shell scripts [don't normally do that kind of thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Anyway it's very likely that you would have a much easier time if you used `read` to split the lines into multiple fields, using `while IFS=';' read -ra row_cells; do [...]; done < data.text` ; [sample here](https://ideone.com/kHGdUC)

Comment: @John Kugelman i want to use information from each line to perform specific operations for example. I  am trying to read each line from the file and if id == 10010101010 then *do something* and then checks the second line and do the same. so basically iterating through he file and based on some values, i am going to perform certain operations

Comment: "row[0] is the first row and row[2] is the second row" Then row[1] is the first and a half row?

Comment: Then don't bother with arrays and use read to split each line around `;` into 4 fields, which you will be able to test separately as needed

Comment: Or simply use `awk`. While bash is capable of splitting lines into fields, and can for short files, if you have a large dataset, `awk` will be *Orders of Magnitude* faster in accomplishing the same thing. Learn how to do it in bash, but then learn how it is really done in `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your comment, it looks like a simple `while read` loop is what you need :

```
while IFS=';' read -r id rest; do
    if [[ "$id" == "10010101010" ]]; then
        echo "Matching line : $id $rest"
    fi
done < data.txt
```

In this code `IFS=';'` specifies to use the `;` character as the internal field separator for the command `read`, which will make it parse each one of your lines as four distinct words.

The names following `read -r` correspond to variables to use to store each of these words, the last of them containing the rest of the line if there are more words than variables.
`read -r id rest` will store the first column in the `$id` variable and the remaining words into `$rest`, while `read -r first second third fourth` would store each word in its own variable.

The input of the `read` command is specified at the end of the `while` loop appending `< data.txt` after the `done` closing the loop.

Comment: If you have four fields, `read -r first second third fourth` where each argument is the name of a variable to read a value into.

Comment: Your sample only contains one line which matches the pattern. Are you sure your real data contains multiple occurrences?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [internal field separator (IFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) variable. The internal field separator (abbreviated IFS) refers to a variable which defines the character or characters used to separate a pattern into tokens for some operations.
It will parse one line of items separated by `;`, pushing it into the array `DATA`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=\; read -ra DATA; do
  for i in "${DATA[@]}"; do
    echo -e "$i"
  done
  echo
done
```

The sample script will produce following output:

```
10010101010
99
18767654536
252525

89878337326
44
18764329087
242424
```

Comment: Why would you not simply do `while IFS=$';' read -r -a DATA; do for i in "${DATA[@]}"; do ...` and avoid the whole *herestring*?

Comment: See [this ideone](https://ideone.com/xpewym) if you're confused by @DavidC.Rankin 's comment ; same result, one less `read`.